# Relative XPath selection using XmlNode (c#)

Tags: c#, xpath

Say i have the following xml file:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c></c>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c></c>
  </b>
</a>

var nodes = doc.SelectNodes("/a/b");
```

will select the two b nodes.

I then loop these two nodes suchas:

```
 foreach (XmlNode node in nodes) { }
```

However, when i call `node.SelectNodes("/a/b/c");` It still returns both values and not just the descendants.
Is it possible to select nodes only descening from the current `node`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the `foreach` loop, you already know that `node` is a `/a/b` in the original document - so to get just *its* `c` children simply use a **relative** xpath:

```
node.SelectNodes("c")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `node.SelectSingleNode("C");`

Answer (score 1):

```
/a/b[1]/c
```

For intance gets the nodelist of all the children of the first b that have the tagname c.

To get the first c as a singleton nodelist use /a/b[1]/c[1]. /a/b/c[1] again returns a nodelist of multiple nodes.

SelectSingleNode is probably misleading, as far as I know, XPath always returns a nodelist, which can contain optionally one node (or even be empty).

//c[1] just selects the first c in the document.